# Using $@ for error message passing in module

Tags: perl

I've been working on a fork of a CPAN module which is now unmaintained (as far as I've been able to tell). In this module, they use `$@` to pass error messages up the stack. In other words, they set `$@` if anything goes wrong in any call to subroutines, and they check after the call to see if it is set. I had never seen this variable before, but I thought it was useful, so I started using it the same way in the code. Now I recently read up a bit more about it, and found that its purpose is a bit more narrow than this. Reading [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) (and other SO questions on the matter) doesn't fully answer this for me, but, is it OK to use `$@` this way? Some "punctuation" variables I know should definitely *not* be used in such a general-purpose way (some even with `local`), is this one of those cases, or am I OK continuing this practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$@` is a relatively "unspecial" special variable in Perl. Nothing in Perl ever reads from `$@`, and it's only written to by an `eval {}` block at the end. This makes it relatively safe to use for your own error-signalling purposes.

In particular, the core `IO::Socket` tree of modules use this to indicate the failure from the constructor:

```
use IO::Socket::IP;
my $sock = IO::Socket::IP->new(...) or die "Cannot connect - $@";
```

The more traditional `$!` is unsuitable here because `$!` has magic that wraps the libc-level `errno` construct; meaning it can only be set to an integer `errno` value, even though it can be read as either a number or a string. Because sometimes failures can happen that don't directly relate to `errno` values (in `IO::Socket`'s case, many kinds of resolver failure for example), sometimes `$!` is inappropriate for this.

Answer (score 4):

`$@` is not normally explicitly set.  Rather, it is automatically set for you when an exception is raised.  From [perldoc `die`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html):

> - die LIST
>
>   `die` raises an exception. Inside an `eval` the error message is stuffed into `$@` and the `eval` is terminated with the undefined value. If the exception is outside of all enclosing `eval`s, then the uncaught exception prints LIST to `STDERR` and exits with a non-zero value. If you need to exit the process with a specific exit code, see `exit`.

For example,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

eval {
    print "Hi\n";
    die "Something went wrong here";
    print "Bye\n";
};
print $@;
```

prints

```
Hi
Something went wrong here at ./cr22854919 line 5.
```

It is permissible to use `$@` to pass error messages up the stack in this way, as a kind of try-catch mechanism.  However, since it is a global variable, you should process it as soon as possible after an `eval { }` block to ensure that no other code interferes with your handling of the exception.

---

The other magic variable commonly used for error handling is `$!`, which works like `errno` in C.

Example:

```
my $path = "/tmp/no-such-file";
open F, '<', $path
    or print STDERR "$path: $!\n";
```

Output:

```
/tmp/no-such-file: No such file or directory
```